# The dreaded Lazy Initialization Exception when using JAX-WS and JEE6

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, lazy-loading, java-ee-6

I am getting a LIE when using the JAX-WS @Path and the @Stateless (or @RequestScoped) annotation. The code:

```
@Path("/users")
@Stateless
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class UserResourceRESTService {
  @Inject
  @UserRepository
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @GET
  @Path("/{id:[1-9][0-9]*}")
  public User lookupUserById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
      return em.find(User.class, id);
  }
}
```

The actual exception I am getting:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

The user object has an address, which has a country. If I change this to a stateful bean and use an extended context it works, but this really shouldn't be a SFSB should it? I am at a bit of a loss as to why the "em" wouldn't be able to open a session when using a stateless bean?

Comment: after NullPointerException, this is the most common exception in the java world. What did your searches on google and stackoverflow tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are operating in extended persistence context your returned User entity remains in managed state and when you are using transaction persistence context transaction ends once lookupUserById() method returns and result of that method is an entity which is already detached from persistence context. As a result all properties of that entity which are marked as LAZY are not accessible anymore.

If you want to access these lazy properties after entity became detached from persistence context invoke specific getter methods on that entity prior returning from lookupUserById method.

i.e.

```
 public User lookupUserById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
  User user =  em.find(User.class, id);
  user.getAddress().getCountry();
  return user;
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess the method returns the User object, AND THEN the XML serialisation happens via the @Produces tag - hence the LIE. I am still a little surprised, as it would be quite common to serialise GET requests as XML/JSon in a RESTful manner from a single method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also annotate your relationships in User class with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. If you always return everything it's no point to have lazy loading in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, in this case I have actually taken this approach (using FetchType.EAGER). I was just really curious as it seemed like it would be a common problem for RESSTful services.

Comment: Surely it is a bug, shouldn't the session stay open in a SLSB until after the @Producer has finished producing...???